# ThreadPool wait unti threads are available in the pool (throttling)

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to implement **throttling functionality** to large amount of items being processed within a `ThreadPool`, by limiting only to `250` items being processed (or queued for execution) at a time.

```
pool = ThreadPool(250)

def func(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(3)

i = 0 
while True: # The amount of items is virtually infinite
    i+=1
    # Block here - if there are no free threads available in the pool
    pool.map_async(func,[i]) # Once delegated, don't block and move forward
```

How can I achieve the functionality illustrated in the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a `threading.Semaphore` with the number of threads in your pool and then initialize the thread pool itself with this semaphore. Then each worker will signal that it has completed its task and freed up the thread that is running it by issuing a call to `release` on the semaphore, which increments the semaphore count. The semaphore thus maintains a count of the number of free threads. Before submitting a new task to the pool, a call to `acquire` is made on the semaphore. This will block if the semaphore count is not positive (there is at least one free thread). Otherwise, the semaphore count is decremented (now there is one fewer free thread).

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Semaphore
import time


def func(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    semaphore.release() # show this thread is now free

POOLSIZE = 10

semaphore = Semaphore(value=POOLSIZE)
pool = ThreadPool(POOLSIZE)
i = 0
for i in range(20):
    # Block here - if there are no free threads available in the pool
    semaphore.acquire()
    """
    # to demonstrate that we are blocking, instead of doing a simple semaphore.aquire():
    if semaphore.acquire(blocking=False) is False:
        print('We would block for i =', i)
        semaphore.acquire() # do actual blocking call
    """
    pool.apply_async(func, args=(i,)) # Once delegated, don't block and move forward
# wait for all tasks to complete:
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

**Using a Callback**

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Semaphore
import time


def func(i):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(3)

POOLSIZE = 10

def my_callback(result):
    semaphore.release() # show this thread is now free


semaphore = Semaphore(value=POOLSIZE)
pool = ThreadPool(POOLSIZE)
i = 0
for i in range(20):
    # Block here - if there are no free threads available in the pool
    semaphore.acquire()
    """
    # to demonstrate that we are blocking, instead of doing a simple semaphore.aquire():
    if semaphore.acquire(blocking=False) is False:
        print('We would block for i =', i)
        semaphore.acquire() # do actual blocking call
    """
    pool.apply_async(func, args=(i,), callback=my_callback) # Once delegated, don't block and move forward
    # or:
    #pool.apply_async(func, args=(i,), callback=lambda result: semaphore.release()) # Once delegated, don't block and move forward

# wait for all tasks to complete:
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Wouldn't passing the `semaphore.release` to `apply_async` as `callback` work even better? Like: `pool.apply_async(work_func,args=(None,),callback=semaphore.release)`

Comment: First of all I have updated my answer. I am so used to doing multiprocessing rather than multithreading where each process has its own address space. In this case I did not need a pool initializer function in order for the worker function to have visibility to the semaphore. Second, what a splendid idea using a callback to release the semaphore! However, you cannot do it the way you propose because a callback is passed whatever result the worker function returns and `semaphore.acquire` takes no arguments (doing it your way would cause an exception) . I have provided an example that does work.

Comment: Amazing! In my case I have just used `lambda _: semaphore.release()` as callback instead of writing another function. The semaphore did it, anyways! Cheers to you

Comment: But I am not really clear why you want to even do this. Normally you can submit tasks and they will just sit on a queue waiting for a thread in the pool to become free and once a thread does become free it will very quickly start executing. But with this mechanism you discover that a thread has become free and only then do you enqueue a task for execution. So there will be a slightly greater delay before the task starts executing. It also makes calls to methods like `map`, which submit multiple tasks at once problematic. You don't have to reply; this is just something for you to consider.